# Is it relevant to have a single inline function alone in a C file?

Tags: c, inline, c99

I am seeing this example where I have a `crc32.c` file which contains:

```
inline int32_t crc32_compute(int32_t *buffer, size_t size) {
   ...
}
```

In the header file I find:

```
extern inline int32_t crc32_compute(int32_t *buffer, size_t size);
```

To me the `inline` keyword has no effect because the function should be declared on the header file not on the C file. Is it that correct?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight added to my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct, whoever wrote this code put things the wrong way around. The header file should contain `inline` function, along with its full definition, while the `.c` file should contain `extern inline` declaration, without a definition:

Header:

```
inline int32_t crc32_compute(int32_t *buffer, size_t size) {
   ...
}
```

C file:

```
extern inline int32_t crc32_compute(int32_t *buffer, size_t size);
```

The header will allow the function code to be inlined; the `.c` file will instruct the compiler to emit an externally visible symbol for it.

Answer (score 1):

They forgot a magic word static. Now if compiled by gcc it will be ignored and the compiler will  decide if and how to implement this function. Anyway even if there is no inline keyword the compiler (and the linker if link time optimisation is on) decides how to implement the function invocation - by inlining or traditional call.

If you want to make sure that the function will be inlined or not - you should use proper compiler attributes or pragmas.

where to place and how to declare inline functions depends on compiler, optimisation, link time optimisation and another factors.

Answering your question, if the function should be only visible in the scope of the particular .c file - yes it is - but without the static keyword it will be placed in the object file as well.

Comment: The `static` statement requires the function to be using only on the `crc32.c` file, but this file is aimed to be used externally, so it will be never inlined, right, because the inlining is done by the compiler not the linker. Correct?

Comment: Yes and no at the same time. It is much more complicated nowadays. Modern linkers can do the link time optimisation as well (it is not the domain of the compilers any more). There is no simple answer for this question. You must refer to your compiler / linker documentation. for gcc https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/gcc/Inline.html#Inline

Comment: could you provide a working example to this? The link you gave doesn't show that the inlining is done during the linking phase.

Comment: Read about link time optimisation. And experiment yourself. The link I gave you is compiler related.